# How to monitor mysql connection status in node?

Tags: mysql, node.js

So this is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql,

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

there're 2 parts confuse me,

1. is connection.connect() making the real connection ? i see it's checking for error. But what happens if everything is ok, but i turn off mysql server after 5 minutes, how to monitor the status pls ? 
   Even for pool events, i don't see the disconnect event.
2. for the above code, is there a async/await version for connection.connect() ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can turn it async by any of the mechanisms to promisify callback-style functions. There's both pinging and normal operation errors to deal with disconnects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connection.connect is sync you can use it after connection. To handle connection errors you can use:

```
function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
                                                  // the old one cannot be reused.

  connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                          // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
      handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
      throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
    }
  });
}
```

By the way everything is explained in [node-mysql read me](https://github.com/nickstamas/node-mysql/blob/master/Readme.md)